# Keep InPlaceEditor highlight when losing focus

Tags: delphi

Is there a way in Delphi XE2 to preserve the the InPlaceEditor's highlight in a StringGrid when the grid loses focus to another non-modal form?

My current StringGrid options are:

[image]

If not, I had hoped to use the code below to preserve a highlight of the current cell after losing focus, but am having some trouble with it leaving cells highlighted when they're no longer the current cell.

Do I need to add an "else" to the code below to change the color back to the original on non-selected cells?  Any caveats?

```
  procedure TForm1.sgMultiDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);    
  begin
    if (ACol = sgMulti.Col) and (ARow = sgMulti.Row) then
    begin
      sgMulti.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
      sgMulti.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);  
      sgMulti.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left, Rect.Top, sgMulti.Cells[ACol, ARow]); 
      if gdFocused in State then
        sgMulti.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect); user
    end;
  end; { sgMultiDrawCell}
```

Edit: The screen capture below clarifies how it's behaving today. I want to current cell, when losing focus, to be more clear than the bottom screen capture

[image]

Comment: @TLama: my goal is that the cell remain highlighted in some way when losing focus.  It hadn't occurred to me that as you say, this means leaving the InPlaceEditor in edit mode.  Seems to me that it's unlikely it's possible or preferable to use the InPlaceEditor for that, now that you put it that way. Maybe I should just do the highlighting myself when unfocused? (It's okay if the highlight when unfocused is different than the edit mode highlight.)

Comment: did you try to remove `goAlwaysShowEditor` option?

Comment: @Serg and TLama: I think you're right. Removing the goAlwaysShowEditor is what I want, especially because goEditing is on.  I think I probably set goAlwaysShowEditor some time ago in an effort to make the highlight brighter. How hard would it be enhance the highlighted boundry box or color? Serg: please post your previous comment as an answer. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to keep the `goAlwaysShowEditor` option enabled and highlight just the always displayed editor, you need the access to the `InplaceEditor` property. This needs to subclass your string grid class and change the color of the inplace editor, which is by default `TCustomMaskEdit` control class.
 In this code is shown, how to change the color of the inplace editor, depending on when the string grid
 is focused or not:

```
type
  TStringGrid = class(Grids.TStringGrid)
  private
    procedure CMEnter(var Message: TCMEnter); message CM_ENTER;
    procedure CMExit(var Message: TCMExit); message CM_EXIT;
  protected
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TStringGrid }

procedure TStringGrid.CMEnter(var Message: TCMEnter);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(InplaceEditor) then
    TMaskEdit(InplaceEditor).Color := $0000FFBF;
end;

procedure TStringGrid.CMExit(var Message: TCMExit);
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(InplaceEditor) then
    TMaskEdit(InplaceEditor).Color := $0000A6FF;
end;

function TStringGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  Result := inherited;
  if Focused then
    TMaskEdit(Result).Color := $0000FFBF
  else
    TMaskEdit(Result).Color := $0000A6FF;
end;
```

And the result with the focused and unfocused grid state:

[image]